# Login With PayPal scopes not working properly

Tags: next.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm working on a e-Commerce platform where sellers can sell their services. The only payment gateway I'm using is PayPal, I need to get information about the seller's PayPal account like the email address or account ID to store it and then forward payments to their account when a customer buys something from them, I plan to do this with [Login With Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/).

When I click on the button to sign in and get redirected to http://sandbox.paypal.com/signin, I type my email address and password to obtain a code using `openid profile email` scopes, everything goes as intended, when I add the `https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes` value to the scopes string to get access specifically to the account verification status and PayPal account ID though, I receive an error saying the request couldn't be processed and to try again, therefore never hitting the callback URL containing the code that I need, no matter how many times I try again I get the same error.

[image]

Just in case, I'm using a Sandbox environment. This is my Next.js `Login With PayPal` button code.

```
<Script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/api.js"
            onReady={() => {
            paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {
            login.render ({
            "appid":"...",
            "authend":"sandbox",
            "scopes":"openid profile email 
            https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes",
            "containerid":"lippButton",
            "responseType":"code",
            "locale":"en-us",
            "buttonType":"LWP",
            "buttonShape":"pill",
            "buttonSize":"lg",
            "fullPage":"true",
            "returnurl":"http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/paypal/callback"
        })
    })
}}/>
```

I've also checked `Account verification status` and `PayPal account ID (payer ID)` scopes in my PayPal account settings.

DevTooling the request, this is what I receive:

```
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Invalid request during get consent content",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 3,
                    "column": 5
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "connect",
                "getConsent"
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "name": "INVALID_REQUEST",
                "details": []
            }
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "connect": {
            "getConsent": null,
            "__typename": "ConnectQuery"
        }
    },
    "extensions": {
        "tracing": {
            "version": 1,
            "startTime": "2022-10-07T01:54:28.831Z",
            "endTime": "2022-10-07T01:54:29.053Z",
            "duration": 221889707,
            "execution": {
                "resolvers": [
                    {
                        "path": [
                            "connect"
                        ],
                        "parentType": "Query",
                        "fieldName": "connect",
                        "returnType": "ConnectQuery",
                        "startOffset": 1755903,
                        "duration": 28116203
                    },
                    {
                        "path": [
                            "connect",
                            "getConsent"
                        ],
                        "parentType": "ConnectQuery",
                        "fieldName": "getConsent",
                        "returnType": "ConsentEvaluationResponse",
                        "startOffset": 30085850,
                        "duration": 188656843
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "correlationId": "..."
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you waited ~3 to 9 hours after making changes to the sandbox REST app?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Even more than that.

Comment: Create a new sandbox app, test with it, and if the issue is the same update your question here with all ids from that test, most importantly the app/clientid for reproduction. Maybe the secret as well although it doesn't look like API calls are necessary to reproduce here

Comment: Creating a new sandbox application solved it for me. I was using the Default Application, I don't know if that has something to do with it. Any reason for this to happen? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an account or app in the PayPal Sandbox environment appears to be behaving in a way you can't find an explanation for, the simplest resolution is often to simply create a *new* sandbox account/app and verify whether the problem occurs there as well. If it doesn't, use the new one -- if it does, you have have ruled out the account/app itself as an issue and can focus on configuration/integration issues or a real potential problem to report.